# Is there a way to make a query with an importrange to mimic a sumif formula from another Google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I am encountering a capacity issue with one of my spreadsheets but certain information in the sheet still needs to be available to cross-reference. The original spreadsheet contains this formula:

```
=sumif(A:A,A2,N:N)=O2
```

I tried to do a direct transfer to the new spreadsheet by adding importranges like this:

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A2:A"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A2"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!N2:N")=IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!O2")
```

The equation keeps putting out an error saying "argument must be a range". Then I tried to write it out as a query like this:

```
=QUERY(AND(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A:A"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!N:N"),"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Col1=A2 THEN Col14)=O2"))
```

But the equation is showing `FALSE` as the result when it should say `TRUE`. I have attached an example spreadsheet so that these equations make more sense.

I also need the equation to take into account any new information that is placed on the new spreadsheet while also comparing it with the old info. I tried doing this to start with but then slowly realized the initial equation itself doesn't work.

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A2:A"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!A2"),IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!N2:N"))=IMPORTRANGE("URL","Sheet1!O2")+SUMIF(A:A,A2,N:N)=O2
```

Any help is appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q1cWh58p23dcQulQ4rz6v4iiDywEFHvcrvASao61xxo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

use this formula instead of **`SUMIF`**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(
 IMPORTRANGE("1q1cWh58p23dcQulQ4rz6v4iiDywEFHvcrvASao61xxo","Sheet1!C2:C")), 
 IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 IMPORTRANGE("1q1cWh58p23dcQulQ4rz6v4iiDywEFHvcrvASao61xxo","Sheet1!C2:C"),
 QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1q1cWh58p23dcQulQ4rz6v4iiDywEFHvcrvASao61xxo","Sheet1!A2:N"), 
 "select Col3,sum(Col14) where Col1 is not null group by Col3 label sum(Col14)''"),2,0))=
 IMPORTRANGE("1q1cWh58p23dcQulQ4rz6v4iiDywEFHvcrvASao61xxo","Sheet1!O2:O"), TRUE, FALSE),))
```

[image: 0]